# Showing loading screen while assets load Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loading, preload

I am writing a vue application at the moment, I want to show a loading screen while the JS, CSS, images & videos are loaded.

What is the best way to go about this?

Obviously I can use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert("every thing has loaded");
})
```

But should this be done in an initial Vue component, or should I initial Vue once everything is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it with:

```
v-cloak
```

`v-cloak` is going to hide your code until everything is loaded; so you could try it with that maybe.

You also need to set a css:

```
[v-cloak] {display: none}
```

Here the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Comment: This would an option but I want show loading graphic, and then a video when everything is loaded `v-cloak` looks like it would hide everything?